# find used or unused dnn pages

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

i want to clean up my portal and do some house cleaning.

how can i generate a list of used pages, or on the flip side a list of unused pages?

next, how is it best to remove an unwanted page from a dnn portal?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a database query, which you can run from the Host -> SQL window, that will return all of the pages that do not have modules on them.

```
--list active pages without active modules
select TabID, TabName
from {databaseOwner}{objectQualifier}tabs
where tabid not in (select TabID from {databaseOwner}{objectQualifier}TabModules where IsDeleted = 0)
and IsDeleted = 0
and PortalID = 0 -- update to use your portal id
```

Here is one that lists all of the modules on their site, their page, and the pane in which that module resides on the page.

```
--list modules on pages
select t.TabID, t.TabName, m.ModuleTitle, tm.PaneName
from tabmodules tm
join {databaseOwner}{objectQualifier}Modules m on (tm.ModuleID = m.ModuleID)
join {databaseOwner}{objectQualifier}Tabs t on (t.TabID = tm.TabID)
where t.PortalID = 0 -- update to use your portal id
and tm.IsDeleted = 0
```

The best way to delete a page is to go to the Admin -> Pages page and delete them there. Remember to also visit and maintain your Admin -> Recycle Bin as well to help keep things clean on your site.